# Why is Java boolean primitive type name not 'bool'?

Tags: java, history, boolean

Java has

- `int` and `Integer`
- `boolean` and `Boolean`

This seems a bit inconsistent, why not either

- `bool` vs `Boolean` to use an established shorter name for primitive type?

or

- `integer` vs `Integer` to keep type names consistent?

I *think* C++ had decided to use `bool` quite a bit earlier than Java decided to use `boolean`, and maybe also some (non-standard at the time?) C extensions too, so there would have been historical precedence for `bool`. I've noticed I often instinctively try to use `bool` at first (good thing modern editors immediately spot this without extra compilation round), so it'd be nice to know the rationale behind current state of affairs.

If someone remembers (a part of) the story, or can even find and link to relevant historical discussion in the net, that would be great.

Comment: `boolean` is definitely more explicit than `bool`. I'd rather ask why `int` is not called `integer`. My guess: `int` and `char` where too ingrained to be changed to `integer` and `character`, but `bool` was not yet fully established.

Comment: "I think C++ had decided to use bool quite a bit earlier than Java decided to use boolean" Why do you think that?

Comment: According to [Evolving a language in and for the real world: C++ 1991-2006](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl-almost-final.pdf), the `bool` type was introduced to C++ in 1993. Java included `boolean` in its first release in 1995, but the Java project itself was started in 1991. Without finding further sources of information, it's not clear to me which came first, or what (if any) influence they had on each other.

Comment: The [Oak language specification](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/files/OakSpec0.2.ps) (version 0.2, copyrighted 1994) also includes the `boolean` type. (Oak was later renamed to Java). That pushes the dates even closer, though I still see no definite evidence to show precedence, or influence, in either direction.

Comment: It isn't inconsistent, there are `double` and `Double` as well.

Comment: @vorrtex `boolean` is inconsistent with C/C++ (today also C#), `int` is inconsistent with other Java primitive types, basically they are inconsistent with each other. There must have been discussion about it when decisions were made.

Comment: @JohnBartholomew if you want to convert those comments of yours into an answer, I think I'd accept that, as it's probably closest to historical truth we're going to get here.

Comment: Just a side note, I had asked this same question on stackoverflow a couple of months ago and it was deleted after 5 minutes. Today I asked this on [quora](http://www.quora.com/Java-programming-language/Why-does-Java-use-the-name-boolean-instead-of-bool) and someone gave a link to this question. I'm glad see some answers at last.

Comment: I would rather ask why `Integer` not `Int`. Boxing was introduced much later than the other things like `int`, `boolean`, `bool`, etc. in both C++ and Java.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Without getting in contact with people who were actually involved in these design decisions, I think we're unlikely to find a definitive answer. However, based on the timelines of the development of both Java and C++, I would conjecture that Java's `boolean` was chosen before, or contemporaneously with, the introduction `bool` to C++, and certainly before `bool` was in wide use. It is possible that `boolean` was chosen due to its longer history of use (as in Boolean Algebra), or to match other languages (such as Pascal) which already had a `boolean` type.

## Historical context

According to [Evolving a language in and for the real world: C++ 1991-2006](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl-almost-final.pdf), the `bool` type was introduced to C++ in 1993.

Java included `boolean` in its first release in 1995 ([Java Language Specification 1.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286478.aspx)). The earliest language specification I can find is the [Oak 0.2 specification](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/files/OakSpec0.2.ps) ([Oak was later renamed to Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-1996/jw-10-javaname.html)). That Oak specification is marked "Copyright 1994", but the project itself was started in 1991, and apparently [had a working demo by the summer of 1992](http://gcc.uni-paderborn.de/www/WI/WI2/wi2_lit.nsf/64ae864837b22662c12573e70058bbb4/abf8d70f07c12eb3c1256de900638899/%24FILE/Java%20Technology%20-%20An%20early%20history.pdf).

Answer (score 13):

Actually, Java is more accurate to history here. The theory of true and false values was invented by [George Boole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_boole) and is commonly referred to as [Boolean Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) in his honor.

`bool` is really just a shortcut to avoid a longer name, however, given the auto-completion support of modern IDEs, this is no longer a valid reason (and wasn't even back in the days when Java decided to go for `boolean`).

I have not been part of the decision process for Java, but if someone cares for history, then "Boolean algebra" is the relevant historical precedence, and one might as well question the C/C++ decision on why they mutilated Boole's name by cutting off the `e`.

Comment: Same reason the POSIX call to create a file is called `creat()`.

Comment: So you're saying `int` should be `integer`?

Comment: If you want to be historically accurate, then I think `Boolean` is kind of bad, considering it can have 3 values (`Boolean.FALSE`, `Boolean.TRUE`, `null`)... Point being, programming language symbols and reserved words are always a compromise of several factors, and historical accuracy is probably pretty low on that list.

Comment: I have no intention of being historically accurate, but don't forget, that not all languages allow for that billion-dollar-mistake called `null`.

Comment: @Frank Hey, I'm just converting a specific NullPointerException situation to nicer error reporting and handling, and trying to actively forget *LALALAA* not hearing what you say *LALALAA* ;-)

Answer (score -2):

I can't address the consistency issue, but there's a long history here.

As far as I recall, Algol 60 was the first language to refer to its logical types as 'Boolean'. Algol 60 also had types like 'integer', 'procedure', etc.

Along came Algol 68, and abbreviations seemed to be in vogue: 'bool', 'int', 'proc', etc.

So, language designers can pick whichever style they like, and there's a precedent for it.